# Get Minimum Value From Datagridview Column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, minimum

I want to get the lowest value from My datagridview column!

The name of my datagridview is **datagridview1**

Here my datagridview :

> |-Number-|
>
> |---90---|
>
> |---70---|
>
> |---20---|
>
> |---80---|
>
> |---50---|
>
> |---60---|

I have been try some code :

```
Dim MinVal As Double = 99999999

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

If row.Cells(0).Value < MinVal Then MinVal = row.Cells(0).Value

Next

TextBox9.Text = MinVal
```

There is no Error. But the result is **60** Not **20**

What Happen?? Help Me Please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim Max As Integer = 0

    For Each rws As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Max < rws.Cells(0).Value Then Max = rws.Cells(0).Value
    Next

'Maximum Value
Msgbox(Max)
```

For Minimum You have to Use That Maximum value

```
    Dim Min As Integer = Max

    For Each rws As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Min > rws.Cells(0).Value Then Min = rws.Cells(0).Value
    Next

'Minimum Value
Msgbox(Min)
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
Private Structure cell
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim columnIndex As Integer
End Structure
    Dim cells = From r As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                    Where Not r.IsNewRow _
                    Select CInt(r.Cells(0).Value)

        Dim min As Integer = cells.Min
Dim minval As New cell With {.columnIndex = 0, .rowIndex = Array.IndexOf(cells.ToArray, min)}
```

for maximum---

```
 Dim max As Integer = cells.Max
    Dim maxAddress As New cell With {.columnIndex = 0, .rowIndex = Array.IndexOf(cells.ToArray, max)}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro.. That is working!
Cells(0) = Column(0).??

Comment: If I have 5 Column! I just replace (r.Cells(0).Value) to (r.Cells(ColumnIndex) Right?

Comment: Thank You Very Much!

How About MAXIMUM?

Please add new Answer To explain MAXIMUM.

Comment: I got it!
Thanks Again! :D